# Nim: How to prove not nil?

Tags: nim-lang

To me, one of the most interesting features of Nim is the `not nil` annotation, because it basically allows to completely rule out all sorts of NPE / access violations bugs statically, by the help of the compiler. However, I have trouble to use it in practice. Let's consider one of the most basic use cases:

```nim
type
  SafeSeq[T] = seq[T] not nil
```

An immediate pitfall here is that even instantiating such a `SafeSeq` is not that easy. The attempt

```nim
let s: SafeSeq[int] = newSeq[int](100)
```

fails with error `cannot prove 'newSeq(100)' is not nil`, which is surprising because one might expect that a `newSeq` simply is not nil. A workaround seems to use a helper like this:

```nim
proc newSafeSeq*[T](size: int): SafeSeq[T] =
  # I guess only @[] expressions are provably not nil
  result = @[]
  result.setlen(size)
```

The next problem arises when trying to do something with a `SafeSeq`. For instance, one might expect that when you map over a `SafeSeq` the result should be not nil again. However, something like this fails as well:

```nim
let a: SafeSeq[int] = @[1,2,3]
let b: SafeSeq[string] = a.mapIt(string, $it)
```

The general problem seems to be that as soon as a return type becomes an ordinary `seq` the compiler seems to forget about the `not nil` property and can no longer prove it.

My idea now was to introduce a small (arguably ugly) helper method that allows me to actually prove `not nil`:

```nim
proc proveNotNil*[T](a: seq[T]): SafeSeq[T] =
  if a != nil:
    result = a # surprise, still error "cannot prove 'a' is not nil"
  else:
    raise newException(ValueError, "can't convert")

# which should allow this:
let a: SafeSeq[int] = @[1,2,3]
let b: SafeSeq[string] = a.mapIt(string, $it).proveNotNil
```

However, the compiler also fails to prove `not nil` here. My questions are:

- How should I help the compiler inferring `not nil` in such cases?
- What is the long term goal with this feature, i.e, are there plans to make inferring `not nil` more powerful? The problem with a manual `proveNotNil` is that it is potentially unsafe and against the idea that the compiler takes care of proving it. However, if the `proveNotNil` would only be required in very rare cases, it wouldn't hurt much.

Note: I know that `seq` attempts to be `nil` agnostic, i.e., *everything works fine* even in the `nil` case. However, this only applies for *within Nim*. When interfacing C code, the nil-hiding-principle becomes a dangerous source for bugs, because a `nil` sequence is only harmless on the Nim side...

Comment: I would guess the standard library needs some work there, for example annotating that `newSeq` returns a `not nil` seq

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use **isNil** magic to check for nil:

```
type SafeSeq[T] = seq[T] not nil
proc proveNotNil[T](s: seq[T]): SafeSeq[T] =
  if s.isNil: # Here is the magic!
    assert(false)
  else:
    result = s
let s = proveNotNil newSeq[int]()
```

Comment: Nice, thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I've never heard of `isNil` before e.g. it is not mentioned in the manual. But it makes sense that inferring "not nil" from a conditional requires compiler magic.

Comment: In 2020, `.isNil` is no longer necessary to activate the nil-tracking “compiler magic”, [according to a Nim developer](https://github.com/timotheecour/D_vs_nim/pull/36/#discussion_r399872006). `if s == nil` is enough to satisfy the compiler.